# ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission required even it has been already added

Tags: android, permissions, gps

I have already added `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in manifest but I was reported by *MINT*
`java.lang.SecurityException: "gps"` location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Is this a bug for device? I found an issue in stackoverflow and there was a suggestion to restart a phone.
Please let me know the exact reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your manifest. Also, what is MINT?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> this permission is defined in manifest correctly. I am 100% sure. it is declared before application tag and spelling is correct. and only reported from one device

Comment: @CommonsWare, any thought?

Comment: "and only reported from one device" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: this crash happened for one device

Comment: @CommonsWare, what could be an issue?

Comment: "this crash happened for one device" -- what do you mean by this? Do you mean that you own one device, and your app crashes? Do you mean that you own two devices, and your app crashes on one and not the other? Do you mean that you have an app in production, and out of all the devices that have used it, your app crashed with this error only once? Do you mean something else?

Comment: third case. my app is on production and crashed only once till now.

Answer (score 0):

> my app is on production and crashed only once till now

My guess is that the user isn't running your published app, but a modified version of your app where they removed this permission.

It is conceivable that they are running the published app on a ROM mod that has some privacy controls that would result in this error, but AFAIK usually ROM mods handle it differently (e.g., let you have the permission but then never give you a GPS fix).

Comment: you mean modified version doesn't contain this permission?

Comment: @crasher: Correct. My guess is that they extracted the manifest, removed the permission (and perhaps others, for all I know), and put the revised manifest in a new APK. IIRC, there are tools that automate this, with an eye towards users who have privacy concerns regarding specific permissions.

Comment: I can't believe it. they're normal users and no reason to do such a complicate thing.